# Invariance of slope to direction of change

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if this question is ill-posed- but here goes nothing.
Imagine that we have a straight line:
$$
y=mx+b
$$
Now, we can compute $m,$ which is simply the slope of the line quite
simply, i.e.
$$
m=\frac{\triangle y}{\triangle x}
$$
Here, we can interpret $m$ as representing the sensitivity of $y$
to $x-$where the change can be in either direction. In other words,
we have that
$$
\triangle y=m\triangle x
$$
If x increases by 1 unit, y changes by m- if x decreases by 1 unit,
y changes by -m. Now, my question is as follows- does it make sense
to make a distinction between the *directionality* of the change?
In other words, consider a real life situation. Perhaps decreasing
$x$ has a different effect on $y$ than increasing $x$ does. Initially,
I thought one could model this as a non-linear function of $x,$ such
that:
$$
y=f(x,x^{2},...)
$$
but the partial effect of $x$ on $y,$i.e. $\frac{dy}{dx}$ would
still be the same up to the sign, for a given change (increase or
decrease, from a given point to a given point). My question therefore
is: does it ever make sense to talk about differences in going to
$x_{1}$ to $x_{2}$ vs. going from $x_{2}$ to $x_{1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a general function $f,$ you can take two values $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain of $f$ and write
$\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$ and $\Delta y = f(x_2) - f(x_1).$
The two points $(x_1, f(x_1))$ and $(x_2, f(x_2))$ both lie on the graph of $f$ given by $y = f(x)$ in a Cartesian $x,y$ plane.
The straight line that passes through those two points is a *secant line* of the graph of $f,$ and the slope of that secant line is $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$

It happens that if $f(x) = mx + b$ then all the secant lines of the graph of $f$ are exactly the same as the graph of $f$ itself: the same straight line.
But in the more general case this is usually not true.
For example, if $f(x) = x^2$ and $x_1 = 0$ then every possible different choice of $x_2$ gives you a different secant line, each with a different slope.
In this example the secant line for any $x_2 > x_1$ always has a greater slope than the secant line for $x_2 < x_1.$
So if you fix one point ($(x_1,f(x_1))$) and then choose a second point,
it can indeed make a difference in the slope of the *secant line* depending on whether you put the second point to the left or right of the first point.

The notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is defined when the secant lines converge to a unique limiting case under specific conditions given in the definition of $\frac{dy}{dx}.$
If the limiting case is not unique, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not defined.

That is, by definition, if $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists then it has the same value
(you don't even have to say "up to the sign" -- the sign also will be the same)
no matter which direction you look, left or right.

If you plot the graph of $y = f(x) = \lvert x \rvert,$ on the other hand,
there is an angle in the graph at $(0,0)$. If you let $x_1 = 0$ then the secant line between $(x_1, f(x_1))$ and $(x_2, f(x_2))$ has slope $1$ whenever $x_2 > 0$ and slope $-1$ whenever $x_2 < 0.$
This implies that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not defined at $x = 0.$
That is precisely *because* you get two different values of
$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ depending on whether you look to the left or to the right.

Ironically, if you literally are just asking about the difference between going from $x_1$ to $x_2$ or from $x_2$ to $x_1,$ note that when going from $x_1$ to $x_2$
we write $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$ and $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1 = f(x_2) - f(x_1).$
So
$$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}. $$

On the other hand, if we go from $x_2$ to $x_1,$ we have $\Delta x = x_1 - x_2,$ $\Delta y = y_1 - y_2 = f(x_1) - f(x_2),$ and
$$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2}. $$

But
$$
\frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}
$$
as long as $x_1 \neq x_2$ and as long as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both in the domain of $f$, no matter what other properties the function $f$ does or does not have.
So it is impossible to find an example of a function $f$ for which these two versions of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ are both defined and are different from each other.

Comment: Very well explained. I had thought the same. However, in a real world setting - it may very well be different...increasing an argument may have a different magnitude of effect on the outcome, than decreasing it might...

Comment: Increasing an argument by $1$ unit can have a larger impact that decreasing by $1$ unit even in a pure mathematical function, because then the only kind of "slope" that matters is the slope of the secant line. It is only the *instantaneous* change $dy/dx$ that is required to be unique (if it exists). Also note that in reality not everything that has an input and an output is a function. For example, you might push the accelerator pedal of a car farther down to make the car go faster, but the speed of the car is not a function of the accelerator pedal's position.

Comment: Understood. Many thanks. I would really appreciate it if you could also look at my most recent query :) An easy accept- yours for the taking.

Answer (score 0):

Incontinuos functions could be a good candidate.
(Sadly I cannot comment yet, if it's considered bad, apologies in advance.)